# How to make Jest transform Material UI style helpers?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui

I'm writing Jest unit tests for ReactJS components that use Material UI `makeStyles`. For most of them it works fine, but gives  `Unexpected token` error for `theme.breakpoints` queries:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

   8 |         order: 3,
   9 |         marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
> 10 |         [theme.breakpoints.up("md")]: {
     |                                               ^
  11 |             order: 2,
  12 |             marginTop: theme.spacing(1.5)
  13 |         },

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (../node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
  at ScriptTransformer.transform (../node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
  at Object.<anonymous> (../src/components/StatusHeader/StatusHeaderStyles.js:10:47)
```

My jest config is as follows:

```
{
  rootDir: "tests",
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(j|t)sx?$": "babel-jest",
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.(css)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    "../node_modules/@testing-library/jest-dom/dist/index.js",
  ]
}
```

If to comment out `theme.breakpoints`, tests runs successfully. How do I make Jest parse those style helpers?

Answer (score 1):

In your test file, you can wrap the component you are testing in a ThemeProvider with a them created by createMuiTheme ([more here](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/))

Here's a sample:

```
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core';
other imports...

describe('MyComponent' => {
  Do your set up....

  it('should render correctly', () => {
  const theme = createMuiTheme();
  const component = mount(
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <MyComponent />
  </ThemeProvider>
  );
  expect(toJson(component)).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```